# CSS position causes tablet browser to black out

Tags: android, ios, css, ipad, tablet

On especially Apple Ipad air, or ipad mini (retina) these [site](http://www.karrebaekskole.skoleintra.dk/) goes completely dark gray for approx. 30 seconds, before the site appears.

On PC/Mac or most smartphones, along with android based tablets, the page layout renders nicely.

I've narrowed it down - I hope - to CSS "position" of the wrappers.

If I remove the `position: absolute;` on #hoejrewrap and #hovedwrap, and `position: relative` on #indholdsramme, the problem is solved, but introduces overlapping divs on tablet or zooming in/out in all other browsers.

Any clues?

Trin

Comment: Post the codes here please.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7QW4R/1/ - warning: ack-old CMS is used for the site, so the jsfiddle isn't complete. But the HTML and CSS should give you a fair look.

Comment: Works fine on ipad peek btw. But not on ipad hardware.